# How to use StreamBuilder with model and fetch data from firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm want to get data from firestore and use it with model using StreamBuilder but I'm getting null when use it. I have defined the type in streambuilder with the model but when using it gives null. Below is my code.

Stream function for fetch data.

```
Stream<List<DrModel>> getSearch() {
    final stream = db
        .collection("doctor")
        .where("searchkey", arrayContains: searchValue)
        .snapshots();
    return stream.map((event) => event.docs.map((doc) {
          return DrModel.fromJson(doc.data());
        }).toList());
  }
```

Model: Code for Model is [here](http://collabedit.com/45ru5)

StreamBuilder:

````
body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: getSearch(),
        
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<DrModel>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(snapshot.error),
            );
          }
         
          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              //final item = doctorList[index];
              final data = snapshot.data[index];
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(fixPadding * 2.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 100.0,
                              height: 100.0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: whiteColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                                border:
                                    Border.all(width: 0.3, color: primaryColor),
                                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    blurRadius: 1.0,
                                    spreadRadius: 1.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                                  ),
                                ],
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(data.drImage),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                  ),
                  
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        },
    ```
````

Comment: everything is fine here and the reason I'm getting null is the String name in Where clause is searchKey rather than searchkey .

Comment: do you still need help with this?

Comment: `A value of type 'Future<List<Iterable<dynamic>>>' can't be returned from the method 'getSearch' because it has a return type of 'Stream<List<DrModel>>'` I;m getting this error while getting Stream only. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @NadeemShaikh actually code is working but the thing in query is entered the wrong name i.e searchkey instead of searchKey. Can you share your code might be issue with your code because your return type is different as Future.

Answer (score 1):

You can always reference the model in streams or futures.

You should try doing something like this:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
        stream: getSearch(),
        
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<DrModel>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(snapshot.error),
            );
          }

          // You can create your own new class method in the `DrModel`
          // model called `fromDocument` which expects you to pass in a
          // document. Then it will check the snapshot you provided and
          // basically parse it to return a `DrModel` where you can then
          // use any of it's values.
         
          DrModel _doctor = DrModel.fromDocument(snapshot);

          // You will also need to return if loading because the stream
          // might still be loading the data.
          else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: Text('Loading...'));
          }
         
          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              //final item = doctorList[index];
              final data = snapshot.data[index];
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(fixPadding * 2.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 100.0,
                              height: 100.0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: whiteColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                                border:
                                    Border.all(width: 0.3, color: primaryColor),
                                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    blurRadius: 1.0,
                                    spreadRadius: 1.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                                  ),
                                ],
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(data.drImage),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                  ),
                  
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        },
```

Comment: See in my model I have given a link where my parse is fromJson. So, Did I need to change it to fromDocument? and for hasError I have added the code but no error will not appear on screen. I think that I have not receive the data into my model, Is my model correct?

Comment: please help me this above problem I still facing problem. @Ziyad

Comment: are you still facing the problem?

Comment: @Zuher Abud Said the problem is solved but Geolocation is not parsing. Do you have any idea?

Comment: ask your question separately